# Problems with IntelliJ integration after switching SVN servers

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

We moved to another SVN server, and now my IntelliJ-SVN integration doesn't work. Whenever I open the project, I get this:

[image]

What is this "content roots"? I searched all over the project dir and didn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

"VSS" suggests "Visual Source Safe".  Ugh!

You don't say if your project and all its artifacts have been moved into the new SVN server, but if they have I'd recommend blowing away your old working directory and checking out from SVN into a new one.

"Create project from existing sources" and checking out from your new Subversion repository should sort it out.

Comment: I'm not using VSS, I may have selected it by mistake in IntelliJ.

Comment: And this was a fresh checkout, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Check VCS settings in Idea 11.1 under `File -> Settings... -> Version Control`. The VSC column on the right should be set to Subversion, in your case. Perhaps you should add an entry for your project.

You can also try to set "Use system default Subversion configuration directory" in Subversion options.